# how to identify the exception if file is not found while Reading (Spring Batch)

Tags: spring-batch, batch-processing

I have just started working on Spring Batch (version 3.0.6). I have a job and inside step I'm having Reader->Processor->Writer.

How we can catch or identify the exception is thrown if file is not found while reading. In this case I want to trigger email.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `StepExecutionListener` to process the exception that is thrown by the `ItemStream#open` (as the opening of a file in the `FlatFileItemReader` is), sending your email from there.  To get the exception that caused the failure, you can look at `StepExecution#getFailureExceptions` which will contain the exception that caused the step to fail.

You can read more about the `StepExecutionListener` in the javadoc here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/StepExecutionListener.html

Comment: I already tried ItemReaderListener (OnError method). but what I found is that if file is not present (I have given incorrect file name purposely), its throwing **org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Failed to initialize the reader** . The listener onReadError method not getting executed.

Comment: Ah.  Sorry about that.  I forgot that the open of the file occurs in the `ItemStream#open`.  In that case, use the `StepExecutionListener#afterStep`.  Within the provided `StepExecution#getFailureExceptions`, you'll find the exception that caused the error.  I've updated my answer accordingly.